# Is there a way to convert 'char**' to 'double' in assignment in C++?

Tags: c++

I am trying to limit user input execution to numbers only, when they enter a / b instead of 8 / 2 the result is zero, but I want to give them a warning when they tried to enter something like this.
When I execute my code I am getting error that not possible to convert `char**` to `double` in assignment. The character I have implemented for conversion is `numvalidation` to validate the user input just for first value, if input is number then accept else return default message.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char * numvalidation;
    double var1, var2;
    beginning:
    cout << "Enter the First value: ";
    cin >> var1;
    cout << "Enter the second value: ";
    cin >> var2;
    if (var1 != '\0')
    {
        var1 = (&numvalidation);
        if (*numvalidation != '\0')
        {
            cout << "First Value was not a number,Try again with a correct value." << endl;
        }
        {
            cout << "Do you want to continue using the Calculator? (Y/N)" << endl;
            char restart;
            cin >> restart;
            if (restart == 'y' || restart == 'Y')
                goto beginning;
        }
    }
    cout << "What do you want to do?" << endl;
    cout << "+ :Addition is available" <<endl;
    cout << "- :Subtraction is available" <<endl;
    cout << "* :Multiplication is available" <<endl;
    cout << "/ :Division is available" <<endl;
    cout << "Please chose one of the option below" <<endl;
    char decision;
    cout << "Decision: ";
    cin >> decision;
    system ("cls");
    switch (decision)
    {
        case '+':
            cout << var1 << " + " << var2 << " = " << "" << ( var1 + var2 ) <<endl;
            break;
        case '-':
            cout << var1 << " - " << var2 << " = " << "" << ( var1 - var2 ) <<endl;
            break;
        case '*':
            cout << var1 << " * " << var2 << " = " << "" << ( var1 * var2 ) <<endl;
            break;
        case '/':
            if (var2 == !0)
                cout << var1 << " / " << var2 << " = " << "" << ( var1 / var2 ) <<endl;
            else
                cout << "The value you have entered is invalid because you cannot divide any number by zero " <<endl;
            break;
        default:
            cout << "You have not entered the correct data";
    }
    {
        cout << "Do you want to continue using the Calculator? (Y/N)" << endl;
        char decision2;
        cin >> decision2;
        if (decision2 == 'y' || decision2 == 'Y')
            goto beginning;
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like homework. I would recommend that you go back to simpler problems and get a better understanding of the basics. Judging from the code you have posted here, this specific task is too advanced at the moment. You need to get a better understanding of what is actually going on on each line of your code.

Comment: `char * numvalidation` this is pointer i.e. `long`, simply change it to `char  numvalidation[256] = {'\0'}`;

Comment: `(var1 != '\0')` is always `true`

Comment: @odyss-jii Oh, so I must go to this step later.

Comment: @VictorGubin it is still not working because now it gets the same error on another line.where var1 = (&numvalidation);

Comment: @anonymous What should take me to the solution?

Comment: You can use https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/from_chars

Comment: @VictorGubin The problem is solved )

Comment: @anonymous The problem is solved )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have just solved the Issue and make it possible to convert char** to double by using the Reference of  **Victor Gubin** and **Anonymous** from the above comments on the questioned post.
Here is the code but if you found any bug please let me know with a fix.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main() {
  char numvalidation[256] = {'\0'};
  double var1, var2;
  var1 != '\0';
  beginning:
    cout << "Enter the First value: ";
  cin >> var1;
  cout << "Enter the second value: ";
  cin >> var2;
  cout << "What do you want to do?" << endl;
  cout << "+ :Addition is available" << endl;
  cout << "- :Subtraction is available" << endl;
  cout << "* :Multiplication is available" << endl;
  cout << "/ :Division is available" << endl;
  cout << "Please chose one of the option below" << endl;
  char decision;
  cout << "Decision: ";
  cin >> decision;
  system("cls");
  switch (decision) {
  case '+':
    cout << var1 << " + " << var2 << " = " << "" << (var1 + var2) << endl;
    break;
  case '-':
    cout << var1 << " - " << var2 << " = " << "" << (var1 - var2) << endl;
    break;
  case '*':
    cout << var1 << " * " << var2 << " = " << "" << (var1 * var2) << endl;
    break;
  case '/':
    if (var2 == !0)
      cout << var1 << " / " << var2 << " = " << "" << (var1 / var2) << endl;
    else
      cout << "The value you have entered is invalid because you cannot divide any number by zero" << endl;
    break;
  default:
    cout << "Only Number are Allowed, Please try again ";
    break;
  } {
    cout << "Do you want to continue using the Calculator? (Y/N)" << endl;
    char decision2;
    cin >> decision2;
    if (decision2 == 'y' || decision2 == 'Y')
      goto beginning;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The following code asks for a double until it gets a valid double.

It uses `std::string`. You can use `isdigit()` only but it will be ridiculous (in my opinion).

```
#include<string>
#include<iostream>
#include<cctype>

int main(){

    double var1{};
    std::string temp{};
    size_t processed_chars_no{};


    do{
        std::cout<<"Enter a valid double value: \n";
        std::cin >> temp;
        if( isdigit(temp[0]) )var1 = std::stod( temp, &processed_chars_no );
    }
    while ( processed_chars_no != temp.size() );

    std::cout<<"\n"<<var1;

}
```

Comment: The perfect alternative and I have learn't new Ideas from your code.